# Fabric takes previous ios archive for upload every time

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have Fabric 1.3.7, every time app is archived, previous archive version is taken for upload.

Please can you suggest how can I struggle this.
Now I have to archive app twice every time to workaround this.

Comment: Hey Igor,

Mike from Fabric here, that sounds a bit odd, but we follow Xcode's lead on which version to use. If you try a clean before the Archive, does that do the trick?

Comment: Is there any way to upload ready archive without rebuilding? http api or just drag&drop to fabric?

Comment: If you open up Fabric.app, select the Beta tab and then click on the arrow next to "Active". You can re-distribute any Archives through Beta.

Comment: But if archive not in mentioned list, is there any way to add it to fabric?

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood. As we need to re-sign the build to distribute it, there isn't a way to do this currently.

Comment: Still have this issue, clean also does not help

Comment: It would be great to get more logs from you to dig deeper into this. Mind dropping me a note at support(at)fabric(dot)io?

Comment: @IgorPalaguta, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @WilliamGrand Now I use fastlane for uploading builds to fabric

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem even in 2017. My workaround is:

1. Go back to list of archives.
2. Click "ACTIVE" select box button and change it to "ARCHIVES".
3. Select the correct archive and click on "Distribute".